# NLTK for Named Entity Recognition

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, text-processing, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to use NLTK toolkit to get extract place, date and time from text messages. I just installed the toolkit on my machine and I wrote this quick snippet to test it out:

```
sentence = "Let's meet tomorrow at 9 pm";
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
print nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tags, binary=True)
```

I was assuming that it will identify the date (tomorrow) and time (9 pm). But, surprisingly it failed to recognize that. I get the following result when I run my above code:

```
(S (GPE Let/NNP) 's/POS meet/NN tomorrow/NN at/IN 9/CD pm/NN)
```

Can someone help me understand if I am missing something or NLTK is just not mature enough to tag time and date properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

The default NE chunker in nltk is a maximum entropy chunker trained on the ACE corpus (http://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2005T09). It has not been trained to recognise dates and times, so you need to train your own classifier if you want to do that.

Have a look at http://mattshomepage.com/articles/2016/May/23/nltk_nec/, the whole process is explained very well.

Also, there is a module called timex in nltk_contrib which might help you with your needs. https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/blob/master/nltk_contrib/timex.py

Comment: Thanks!! Links are very helpful!!

Comment: that second link is broken :(

Comment: @xyz Link fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Named entity recognition is not an easy problem, do *not* expect any library to be 100% accurate. You shouldn't make any conclusions about NLTK's performance based on one sentence. Here's another example:

```
sentence = "I went to New York to meet John Smith";
```

I get

```
(S
  I/PRP
  went/VBD
  to/TO
  (NE New/NNP York/NNP)
  to/TO
  meet/VB
  (NE John/NNP Smith/NNP))
```

As you can see, NLTK does very well here. However, I couldn't get NLTK to recognise `today` or `tomorrow` as temporal expressions. You can try Stanford SUTime, it is a part of Stanford [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)- I have used it before I it works quite well (it is in Java though).

Comment: Actually NLTK provides bindings for Stanford's NERTagger (`from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger`). Still you need to download the java source but there is plenty of help out of there.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to correctly identify the **date** or **time** from the text messages you can use **Stanford's NER**.

It uses the **CRF**(Conditional Random Fields) Classifier. CRF is a sequential classifier. So it takes the sequences of words into consideration.

How you frame or design a sentence, accordingly you will get the classified data.

If your input sentence would have been `Let's meet on wednesday at 9am.`, then Stanford NER would have correctly identified `wednesday` as date and `9am` as time.

NLTK supports Stanford NER. Try using it.